# What are my transport options from Macau Airport to downtown Macau?

Tags: public-transport, china, airport-transfer, macau

What's the best way to get from MFM airport to Macau (for definiteness, the area near Vasco da Gama Garden) around 6:30 PM on a weekday?

According to [this website](http://www.macau-airport.com/en/transportation/public-transport/shuttle-bus), there are free shuttles. But that page doesn't tell where exactly they go to. Google Maps suggests bus 26.

Comment: Are you staying at a hotel? Hotels usually have free shuttle buses.

Comment: Not from the airport, only from the ferry ports.

Comment: I think it's easiest to take the Wynn shuttle and then walk for 20 minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Wikivoyage](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Macau#By_plane), you have a few options:

- The light rail system serves the airport.
- Bus AP1 plies a route between the airport and the Barrier Gate. Its route passes through several points on Taipa Island, and it stops at the ferry terminal on the peninsula on the way. It costs MOP$4.20 per passenger, MOP$3 per bag. It has limited provision for baggage, and can be very crowded (you may not even get the first bus to arrive). Change at the ferry terminal for other destinations, the frequent number 3 bus runs from the ferry terminal and passes the Lisboa, Landmark Hotel, and Holiday Inn, or catch one of the hotel/casino shuttles which go the ferry terminal. The buses do not give change, but there is a currency exchange just inside the terminal that will change foreign currency into low denomination MOP.
- Alternatively, take a metered taxi straight to your destination, but there's a MOP$5 airport surcharge plus MOP$2 for the bridge and MOP$3 per bag. Fares to the city center are around MOP$40–50, the trip taking 15–20 minutes.

For anyone else reading this, if continuing on to Hong Kong, use the Express Link from the airport, however be aware it only runs from **11am to 6pm**.

Comment: The Macau light rail currently serves only the southern islands (Taipa/Coloane) and doesn't go anywhere near Vasco da Gama on Macau itself.  The extension to the north won't open until 2023 at the earliest, and you'd still need to connect from there.